# run newest version of file via batch

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to find the simplest way to call the newest file version in a folder to run.

For example, `C:\users\user\Desktop\filestest` contains 4 files:

> ```
> program-A.0011.exe
> program-A.0012.exe
> program-A.0013.exe
> program-A.0014.exe
> ```

With `0014` being the newest version, but possibly not the last modified file.

`cd C:\users\user\Desktop\filestest && program-A.%v%.exe` with `%v%` being the highest variable? What am I missing here?

keep in mind the files are sorted in no particular order, I'm just looking for a way to call the latest version. in this case 0014

[Test .exe files here](https://github.com/zprall/Zprall/)

Comment: what is the actual naming convention of the files? You cannot give dummy examples that makes no sense.. a lot matters with examples like these. So give a minimal, complete and verifiable example please. Until then, this will be voted as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Also, please use Windows path separators, **`\ `**, not 'nix based ones **`/`**.

Comment: question has been updated with github link of example .exe files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this one out. 
This can easily break if naming structure changes, but it does exactly what I need it to do for the moment. 
thanks everyone for the input.

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\filetest"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set max=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-.0" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d program-A.*.exe') do if %%B gtr !max! set max=%%B
echo higest version: program-%max%

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file names are always formatted such that the "latest" on would be sorted last, you can use a `FOR` loop to find it. This is not tested.

```
SET "THEDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\filestest"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B /O:N "%THEDIR%\program-A.*.exe"') DO (SET "LATEST=%%~a")
ECHO The latest file is "%THEDIR%\%LATEST%"
```

If you wanted to get ahead into PowerShell, you could:

```
$Latest = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\filestest -Filter 'program-A.*.exe' |
    Select-Object -Last 1).FullName
```